# Access a variable from the Global Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

How would I access a global variable from a function different from the one that has been modified it?

```js
global_variable;
function getInfo() {
  global_variable = 3; 
}
length = global_variable.length;
function getDuration() {
  console.log(global_variable);
}
```

The problem is here: https://github.com/MANTENN/Days4God/blob/master/playergenerator.html#L154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create global variable the correct way:

```
var global_variable
```

than functions:

```
function getInfo() 
{
  global_variable = 3; 
}

function getDuration() 
{
  console.log(global_variable);
}
```

and than run the functions:

```
getDuration(); // Here you get variable is undefined, instead of not defined error
getInfo();
getDuration(); // Here you will get 3;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ottu451/)

Comment: https://github.com/MANTENN/Days4God/blob/master/playergenerator.html
how come it doesn't work here? line 154?

Comment: `var runs = links.length-1;
function appendAudio(n) {
 /* var runs; */ ` you are re-assigning `runs` inside of the function.

Comment: I removed it, now it is running infinitely. because it can not get the length of links

Comment: why will this not work?
var links;
function getInfo() {
   links = [0,1,2,3,4];
}
var runs = links.length;
function getDuration() {
console.log(runs)
}

Comment: that would work however when I take the length of the links it will not work

Comment: You are not taking the length, you receiving an array of `a`

Try this:
 `links = $("a").length;`

If you are hitting a wall, and you don't know why - always `console.log()` your way. on every variable possible until you get to your answer :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bspfvuwg/
that works but this won't, how come. I tried to design it that way it wouldn't use much ram by declaring it once globally. 
https://jsfiddle.net/85jcujuw/

Comment: that's what I meant, it's the variable name. I'm sorry for being confusing.
I do that. I do not understand why it is zero.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. try to move `var i = 0;
var runs = links.length-1;` before `$.each()` and it will work.

Comment: Can you flag this question for me. I will get an answer eventually in lifetime.

Comment: Can't. @NazariyMaksimchyk but isn't moving the variable to before the call for the function, didn't fix your problem? the problem is that when you call your function, runs is still undefined(you defined it further in the script).

Comment: `var runs` inside the function work for the obvious reason - is defined inside of the function itself

Comment: I moved it in and it worked. But I am trying to understand why it didn't work outside and write higher quality code in the future.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
at appendAudio (playergenerator101.html:155)
at createFile (playergenerator101.html:152)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (playergenerator101.html:65)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it to work and made it more efficient on CPU. Maybe the server too. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz3VpjSRhq0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Define global_variable. 
    var global_variable;

    // optionally you can initialize the global variable like below
    // var global_variable = 0;
    // Or global_variable = 0;

    function getInfo() 
    {
      global_variable = 3; 
    }
    function getDuration() 
    {
      getInfo();
      alert(global_variable);
    }

    // test invoke
    getDuration();
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to define your variable, otherwise it's going to print 'undefined'.

Comment: Yes I know that, however I am not going to call on getDuration right away. The problem is once I call on getInfo and then getDuration() it still is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how any code is executed. The variable "Length" will be 0.

With it and based on my recursive function, it was looping.